# Apache LDAP auth

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ldap

Here is my php code which works fine

```
    $ldapconfig['usersdn'] = 'abc@def.com';//CHANGE THIS TO THE CORRECT USER OU/CN
    $ds=ldap_connect("ldap://something.somewhere.com");
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 10);
    
    $dn = $ldapconfig['usersdn'];
    if(isset($_POST['txtuser'])){
        if ($bind=ldap_bind($ds, $dn, $password)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
        } else {
    
            echo "Login Failed: Please check your username or password";
        }
    }
```

I want to implement the same functionality on the apache server.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
LDAPReferrals off
AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://something.somewhere.com"
AuthName "AD authentication"
Require valid-user
```

I'm also a bit confuse how to pass the username and password witch I enter to the dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using two directives in mod_authnz_ldap.so

```
AuthLDAPInitialBindAsUser
AuthLDAPInitialBindPattern
```

> By default, the server either anonymously, or with a dedicated user
> and password, converts the basic authentication username into an LDAP
> distinguished name (DN). This directive forces the server to use the
> verbatim username and password provided by the incoming user to
> perform the initial DN search.

sample configuration like

```
   AuthType Basic
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthLDAPInitialBindAsUser on
   AuthLDAPInitialBindPattern (.+) $1@def.com
   AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://something.somewhere.com:636/DC=example,DC=com?cn?sub"
   AuthName "AD authentication"
   Require valid-user
```

You can see that the `AuthLDAPInitialBindPattern`  uses regular expression to capture user's input